Fulfill function doesn't work in Chainlink Function Contract for calling external API
Now I am trying to call external API on Chainlink Function Contract.
I created an API, tested it with Postman. It works well.
This is the response of the API.
{
"price": 11192.32
}
And now I am trying to call the API in the chainlink contract.
This is the contract code.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import {Chainlink, ChainlinkClient} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {LinkTokenInterface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";

contract RolexPriceConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public price;
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestPrice(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 price);

    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        _setChainlinkToken(0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789);
        _setChainlinkOracle(0x6090149792dAAeE9D1D568c9f9a6F6B46AA29eFD);
        jobId = "ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18;
    }

    function requestRolexPrice(
        string memory _url
    ) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = _buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector  
        );

        req._add("get", _url);
        req._add("multiply", "100000000");
        req._add("path", "price");

        requestId = _sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        uint256 _price
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestPrice(_requestId, _price);
        price = _price;
    }

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        return price;
    }

    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(_chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}

I deployed this contract on Sepolia Testnet, verified it.
When I deploy this contract, the API is called.
But the getlatestPrice returned 0 in Sepolia Scan.
I think fulfill function isn't called correctly. But I am not sure exactly.
I'd be appreciate if you help me.
I ran this code
function requestRolexPrice(
    string memory _url
) public returns (bytes32) {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = _buildChainlinkRequest(
        jobId,
        address(this),
        this.fulfill.selector  
    );

    req.add("get", _url);        // Use `add` instead of `_add`
    req.add("path", "price");    // Correct method call
    req.add("multiply", "100000000");

    // Send the request and store the requestId
    bytes32 requestId = _sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);

    // Return the requestId
    return requestId;
}



Please amend the question as this contract is NOT using Chainlink Functions (as called out by Syed) but is using the deprecated Chainlink Any API interface.   Any API is the much harder approach - recommend refactoring to use functions.

The correct field to multiply the result (to remove decimals) is times, and it expects a numeric value. Therefore, you should use either req._addUint or req._addInt.
So, replace this line:
req.add("multiply", "100000000");

with:
req._addUint("times", 100000000);

NOTE: As of now, the recommended way to fetch data from any API into a smart contract is by using Chainlink Functions, rather than utilizing Job Specs and Operator/Oracle contracts that interact with a Chainlink Node.

Thanks for answer.
Do you think that there isn't any issue for running fulfill function in the code?

No, your entire implementation is correct. I’ve replicated it on my end, and by applying the fix/replacement I mentioned, it will work perfectly, updating the value of the price variable correctly.

Just redeploy your contract after doing that fix, fund it with 0.1 LINK and call the requestRolexPrice function.

Thanks.
I fixed the err and fetched price.
But I want to fetch the price continuously, but in this case, I only fetch one time.
I run the backend on Nginx, and when deploy the contract, the API is called one time.
Could you give me any advice for this case?

You can use Chainlink Automation for that. Feel free to open a new question and let me know if you face any difficulties.

Thank you very much for your support.

You're welcome. Happy coding and keep building!
